# Crypto JS, not showing expected result when working with arabic or accented characters

Tags: node.js, utf-8, cryptography

I am having an issue generating the correct signature in NodeJS (crypto.js) when the text I am trying to encrypt has Arabic characters (such as أ,ب,ت) or accented characters (such as ä,ï,ë)

So I'm trying to generate the sign using an HMAC SHA256 signature of the req.body payload.

However, my locally generated sign failed to match what I receive from the provider.

And after running the same code on Mac it works, but still on Windows and Linux, it still has the same issue.

So how can I tell crypto to accept UTF-8 encoding in my req.body payload

The code I'm using is:

```js
import crypto from "crypto";
const secret = "secret"
const validateHeaders = (req, res, next) => 
  const hash = crypto
    .createHmac("sha256", secret)
    .update(JSON.stringify(req.body))
    .digest("hex");
  if (hash === req.headers["_signature"]) {
    return next();
  }
return res.sendStatus(401);
```

Again it works on Mac and Mac only for some reason.

Comment: Actually, strings are implicitly UTF-8 encoded (see [here](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#hmacupdatedata-inputencoding)), so the encoding should not be a problem. I can't reproduce the problem under Linux either, the data is UTF-8 encoded as expected and the correct HMAC is generated, see online [here](https://replit.com/@3hK8cL8H24hwiS7/LightcyanBlissfulEmulator#index.js).
So post (non-productive) sample data: Data, generated hmac (hex) and also the expected hmac (hex).

Answer (score 0):

There are basically three reasons why this would go wrong:

1. there is a problem when converting the line ending for the various systems, e.g. by writing out the JSON line-by-line, other white-space may also have changed (tabs to spaces etc.)
2. the byte encoding of the text is changed, e.g. due to various ways of encoding characters with diacritical marks in Unicode, vs characters that have those marks included
3. missing characters / byte that are dropped during copying, e.g. using a terminal that doesn't support Unicode or hidden / control characters that don't get copied at all

In the end you want to protect the content of the message, not so much the *binary representation* of the message; you should not care about whitespace that doesn't have any meaning, for instance. This can be avoided by using canonicalization. This is somewhat easier for binary formats such as ASN.1 / DER encoded structures. For XML and JSON we'll have to [*canonicalize*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonicalization) the message before feeding it into the signature algorithm. For JSON this is standardized in [RFC 8785, specifying "JSON Canonicalization Scheme (JCS)"](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8785) and implemented in, for instance [this canonicalize package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/canonicalize) (I don't know how good it is, but now you know what to look for).

As for the data, well, that's up to you. Store it in a file and take the `sha256sum` of it. If something is wrong they you may need to [normalize your Unicode strings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_equivalence#Normalization) first. If that doesn't help then take a very careful look if the string doesn't get mangled during transport. I have had an instance where e.g. FTP was still used to transport the file, and that meant that the receiving application could only *poll* to see and hope if all the file was received. Please do not copy and paste and/or use a text editor for which you don't know how it actually receives and store the data.

Finally, if the hashes do work out then there is obviously something wrong with the key. HMAC takes a key of any size, and all bytes in the key should be randomized. So it is just as easy to make copying or encoding mistakes (e.g. using a key encoded as hexadecimals instead of the actual bytes that they represent).

---

Notes:

- I suppose you could theoretically misinterpret the output of HMAC as well, but I'll assume that this would be spotted;
- The HMAC `update` method does take a string and needs to convert that string to bytes; as it defaults to UTF-8 I'm assuming that the problem isn't in that line of code.